# Custom content type displayed without theme

Tags: nodes

Working in Drupal 7, I've created a custom content type "Announcement", intended to be distinct from the regular Article type. I haven't added any custom fields or anything esoteric.

The thing works, I can create Announcements and they show up as teasers in a blocks view I have set up for the purpose.

But when I click the teaser link, the announcement page is displayed as a basic HTML page - no theme. I'm using the Marinelli theme and it displays everything else just fine.

Here's the view, located in a sidebar, looks fine:
[image: View block]

---

Clicking the link....

[image: Announcement]

---

What am I missing?

Comment: Are any PHP errors getting logged when you render that page?

Comment: No, there's nothing unusual in the log and no problems indicated in the status report.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up in the end, deleted the content type, recreated it, and it worked. So something must've gone wrong when I first created it, but I never saw an error indication.